# Can jQuery detect a dynamic change to a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to work out if it's possible to detect the change inside a div. With my snippet I'm trying to do an alert when you click `click me` but it doesn't work. My understanding from jQuery's docs is that you can attach the change handler to an element.

```js
$( "#target" ).change(function() {
  console.log( "change detected" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="target"></div>

<span onclick="$('#target').html('changed')">click me</span>
```

Comment: You will need a `MutationObserver` to achieve what you want. The `change` event is only triggered by inputs and so.